# Django admin sortable change-list (grappelli) header displacement

Tags: django, jquery-ui-sortable, django-grappelli

I installed grappelli and the sortable app from ff0000-django-sortable on github and everything works perfectly but one detail you can see in the picture in this [link](http://xleon.net/static/dev/files/sortable-problem.jpg)

The header of the table is displaced to the right. This only happens when the sorting is enabled. If I sort any other field (clicking on other column header) the header looks ok.
I also realize the problem is on the javascript function "$(table).find('tbody').sortable()" in ["django-admin-sortable.js"](https://github.com/ff0000/django-sortable/blob/master/sortable/static/js/django-admin-sortable.js)

I guess this is easy to fix but I can´t find where or how.
Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I guess this is a grappelli related problem. I tried the sortable app in a new project (no grappelli) and it works as expected

Comment: But I still have the same problem with grappelli version...

Comment: Try using https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by a 'float' on the ui-sortable class by JQuery UI, which causes all the cells to float left.This can easily be fixed adding a css file to your admin class.

```
class SortableAdminMixin(object):

    # Make instances reorderable
    list_editable = ('position',)
    list_display = ('position', )

    class Media:
        js = (
            'admin/js/django-admin-sortable.js',
        )

        css = {
            'all': ('admin/css/admin-sortable-fix.css',)
        }
```

The 'admin-sortable-fix.css' file should contain the following line:

```
tbody.ui-sortable {float:none;}
```